# Aplicação IONIC fazendo sincronização automática com servidor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic

Tenho uma aplicação feita com IONIC que faz um CRUD e consegue enviar e receber dados para o servidor, até ai tudo está funcionando perfeitamente. **As modificações que faço na aplicação estão sendo atualizadas no servidor mas não estão sendo atualizadas na própria aplicação**. Utilizei o ng-href em todas minhas chamadas e quando são executadas exibem as informações atualizadas, mas minha lista (ion-list) continua exibindo informações antigas. **Como fazer para que esta lista se atualize com as novas informações do servidor?**

OBS.: Gostaria de algo parecido com um asynctask para o ionic

Comment: Já ouvi falar disso usando meteorjs https://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular1/3-way-data-binding . Vc também pode usar firebase https://www.airpair.com/angularjs/posts/build-a-real-time-hybrid-app-with-ionic-firebase. Não coloco como resposta pois nunca fiz o teste com nenhum deles. Se a sua aplicação estiver usando um banco Mysql talvez seja melhor tentar com o firebase pois ouvi falar que o meteor trabalha bem com o mongo. Se conseguir se sair bem coloca sua solução ai para ajudar. Boa sorte

Comment: André, vou da uma olhada no meteor então, pois meu banco é o Mongo.